# Chrome packaged app security policy

Tags: google-chrome, backbone.js, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I need create RSA signature in my Chrome packaged app written with Backbone.js. But when I use
[jsrsasign](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/) I get:

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an 
allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was 
not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I tried to set up content_security_policy, but it's not working with packaged apps. So how to workaround this?

The code which causes problems is:

```
var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA1withRSA", "prov": "cryptojs/jsrsa"});
```

And the lib is calling eval:

```
this.md = eval(KJUR.crypto.Util.CRYPTOJSMESSAGEDIGESTNAME[alg]).create();
```

Comment: Switch library and/or try to [file an issue](https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/issues) with the original library? You can't relax this policy for apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, it seems that you can patch that line in the library with:

```
this.md = CryptoJS.algo[alg.toUpperCase()].create();
```